# How to manage uploaded code in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

Is there a way to manage interactively (view/delete) config and code of an application in google app engine? I understand that the deployment approach is versioned batch upload, but can i at least download back a collection of uploaded files of current (or any given) revision of an app? Or is there even an interface for GAE similar to CVS/SVN/GIT with features like revisions diff?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to treat App Engine like a version control system. It's not - why not use a version control system?

Comment: @Nick, not neccessarily. i mainly don't like that write-only deployment approach. imagine that you accidentally lost your server code..

Comment: VCSes exist, in part, to prevent you losing your source code. Downloading your code from App Engine should not feature in your list of recovery options.

Comment: @Nick, you are right, but it is still not a sufficient reason, why to deny users to check their own uploaded code, i think

Comment: It's not a matter of denying access - we're implementing a download feature. My point is that you shouldn't be relying on its existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can download your deployed code as of SDK version 1.3.8 according to [the prerelease announcement](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/f79670c37defc6ec)</strike>

This feature was apparently not included in 1.3.8, but it seems to at least be in the works.

> The developer who uploaded an app
>   version can download that version's
>   code    using the appcfg.py
>   download_app command. You can use this
>   to download  both    Python and Java
>   application code.

You can't interactively configure your app, or modify the code without redeploying, however.

Comment: very nice! it's interesting, `download_app` feature is mentioned in [1.3.8 prerelease announcement](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/f79670c37defc6ec), but it's missing in the [announcement](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/94d7e74a2e882b4b) .. maybe it's finally removed after discussion? have to check it

Comment: .. after code inspection this feature was really removed (i mean *hidden* :) )

Comment: well, currently it does not seem to be functional, but it may change soon - it's a hot topic. thanks for a hint!

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot download a deployed application. The only way to see the source is if you have it. You *can* use git/CVS/SVN but it wont have anything to do with the actual deployment of the application.

**Edit:** [Here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html) are the docs

Comment: i don't belive you, can you prove it? :)

Comment: Edit: you see: *Note: Only the developer who uploaded the code can download it. ...* it seem to be a remnant of documentation of temporary `download_app` functionality, which you said was impossible :)

Comment: I know, but you can't do it *now*.